# Cronjob to check files modified on shared hosting

Tags: cron, shared-hosting, cron-task

I need to check if my files are modified, if yes then copy from backup folder (restore the old file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got part of what I was looking:

```
find /home/**/public_html -mtime -1 \! -type d -ls -print0 | mailx -s "Summary of the modified files in $(date +\%d-\%m-\%Y-\%H.\%M.\%S) past hours" myemail@gmail.com
```

But it is giving output with noname file as attachment, how can make it with a timestamp file name?